# Fill Blank ID MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table like the following:

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  3 | Bob   |
|  4 | Alice |
+----+-------+
```

If I add a new row, how do I fill in the blank id (like ID 2, then 4, 5, ..., n) automatically using the function / trigger?

Comment: Hi you are asking about MySQL, SQL server Or Other ?? in this case the SGBD use and version use are important. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** you're using SQL Server (you've tagged both SQL Server and MySQL here) Seems like you're relying on an `IDENTITY` property to reliably provide sequential numbers; it doesn't. As per the documentation, [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL) IDENTITY (Property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017):

> Identity columns can be used for generating key values. The identity
>   property on a column guarantees the following:
>
> - Consecutive values within a transaction - A transaction inserting    multiple rows is not guaranteed to get consecutive values for the
>     rows because other concurrent inserts might occur on the table. If
>     values must be consecutive then the transaction should use an
>     exclusive lock on the table or use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.
> - Consecutive values after server restart or other failures - SQL    Server might cache identity values for performance reasons and some
>     of the assigned values can be lost during a database failure or
>     server restart. This can result in gaps in the identity value upon
>     insert. If gaps are not acceptable then the application should use
>     its own mechanism to generate key values. Using a sequence generator
>     with the NOCACHE option can limit the gaps to transactions that are
>     never committed.

If you need to guarantee that numbers are sequential **at run time**, you can `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN
       [Name]
FROM YourTable;
```

For ID's, there's unlikely to be a *good* reason you need them to be continuous. Having "gaps" in your ID values doesn't really matter, as the (foreign key) constraints and indexes don't care if there are gaps or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
CREATE TABLE temp1 (
        id int,
        name varchar(100)
    );

    select l.id + 1 as id,l.[name]
    from temp1 as l
      left join temp1 as r on l.id + 1 = r.id
    union all 
    Select * from temp1
    order by id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sequence table and after joining your table you can get the missing values in a variables as shown below

```
create table #temp(id int, name varchar(20))
insert into #temp values (1 , 'John'),(3, 'Bob'),(4, 'Alice')

create table #sequence (id int not null primary key);

insert into #sequence(id)
    select 1
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 4
    union all select 6
    union all select 7
    union all select 8
    union all select 9
    union all select 10
    union all select 15
    union all select 16
    union all select 17
    union all select 18
    union all select 19
    union all select 20

    declare @Id int

    select @Id = min (start) from(
    select l.id + 1 as start from #sequence as l
    left outer join #temp as r on l.id + 1 = r.id
    where r.id is null
    )a;

select @Id
```

The output is- `2` after that you can use this variable in any SQL Operation.